# I need to display or hide links depending on state (logged in or not)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is display the "log in" link if the user is not logged in while keeping log out hidden and once the user logs in I want to hide the "log in" link and show the log out link

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "../App.css"
import UserContext from '../contexts/UserContext';

export function logout() {
  localStorage.clear();
  window.location.href = '/';
}
function Nav_Bar() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    
    <div>
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <nav>
          <div className='Nav_bar'>
            <header>
              <img className="main_img" src="https://imgs.search.brave.com/3IR4GEec5MYEziiivB6mEehEmuE2CMoXU8YvwrjB_aM/rs:fit:768:451:1/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1w/bGVjYXBhY2l0eS5j/b20vd3AtY29udGVu/dC91cGxvYWRzLzIw/MTQvMDYvMTctTW9z/dC1TdHVwaWQtUXVl/c3Rpb25zLVBvc3Rl/ZC1Pbi1Ud2l0dGVy/LmpwZw" alt='logo'/>
              <br></br>
              <a href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
              <span> | </span>
              <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
              <span> | </span>
              <a href="/postsList">All tweets</a>
              <span> | </span>
              <a href="/usersList">All users</a>
              <span> | </span>
              <a href='/' onClick={logout}>Sign out</a>
              <hr></hr>
              <hr></hr>
            </header>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Nav_Bar;
```

This is how I am authenticating the user:

```
export const verifyUser = async (req: Request) => {
    console.log(req.headers)
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        try {
            let decoded: any = await jwt.verify(token, secret);
            return await User.findById(decoded.userId);
        }
        catch (err) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my UserContext

```
import React from "react";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: How are you authenticating the user?

Comment: @NeERAJ TK using JWT, I edited my question